# How to delete an item from Sqlite database related to listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that populates data from an sqlite db. When I click on an item in the listview, it goes to a new page that shows the listview item in detail. In that page there is a delete button, which on clicking removes the item from the listview and also from the database.

How is it possible to do that?

Comment: Your question needs clarity. Are you finding problem in deleting row data from your sqllite db or you having difficulty in refreashing listview. Atleast post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

When you are populating the listview from sqlite, poulate an array with the record ids of the records from sqlite table.
Pass the selected record id from that array to the listview detail page.
Then in onClick of the delete button just delete the record from sqlite and repaint your listview from the database.

Comment: Can you show a sample of how to do this associated with sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions:**

```
1. First solution:
```

When user click listView item you send next activity item position which you showing item detail activity, and if user pressed delete and when user back listView activity you send to back this position to listView Activity. And here check if position yes than need remove this item and refresh listView:

```
    listViewAdapter.remove(listViewAdapter.getItem(position));
    listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

For send data to detail Activity and for give data from detail
Activity use onActivityResult method, see more information:
```

[Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

```
2. Second solution:
```

Create Application class extend Application and use it is. Create

```
int selectedItemPosition
boolean itemDeleted
```

field in the Application class. When user click item set this item position to this field and set itemDeleted value false. When user click delete button in the Detail activity you need set itemDeleted value true and when user back listView activity always check itemDeleted value if true delete this item and refresh listView.